# Function that converts a sequence to a list in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I want to convert a sequence to a list using `List.init`. I want at each step to retrieve the i th value of `s`.

```
let to_list s = 
  let n = length s in 
  List.init n 
    (fun _i -> 
       match s () with
       | Nil -> assert false
       | Cons (a, sr) -> a)
```

This is giving me a list initialized with the first element of `s` only. Is it possible in OCaml to initialize the list with all the values of `s`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help to study the [definition](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/6a7a46f00cf7b265c1d3bf19ea8a0736dbff17c1/stdlib/list.ml#L69) of `List.init`.

There are two variations depending on the size of the list: a tail recursive one, `init_tailrec_aux`, whose result is in reverse order, and a basic one, `init_aux`. They have identical results, so we need only look at `init_aux`:

```
let rec init_aux i n f =
  if i >= n then []
  else
    let r = f i in
    r :: init_aux (i+1) n f
```

This function recursively increments a counter `i` until it reaches a limit `n`. For each value of the counter that is strictly less than the limit, it adds the value given by `f i` to the head of the list being produced.

The question now is, what does your anonymous function do when called with different values of `i`?:

```
let f_anon =
  (fun _i -> match s () with
      |Nil -> assert false
      |Cons(a, sr) -> a)
```

Regardless of `_i`, it always gives the head of the list produced by `s ()`, and *if* `s ()` always returns the same list, then `f_anon 0` = `f_anon 1` = `f_anon 2` = `f_anon 3` = `hd (s ())`.

Jeffrey Scofield's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49715015/1088827) describes a technique for giving a different value at each `_i`, and I agree with his suggestion that `List.init` is not the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3):

The essence of the problem is that you're not saving `sr`, which would let you retrieve the next element of the sequence.

However, the slightly larger problem is that `List.init` passes only an int as an argument to the initialization function. So even if you did keep track of `sr`, there's no way it can be passed to your initialization function.

You can do what you want using the impure parts of OCaml. E.g., you could save `sr` in a global reference variable at each step and retrieve it in the next call to the initialization function. However, this is really quite a cumbersome way to produce your list.

I would suggest *not* using `List.init`. You can write a straightforward recursive function to do what you want. (If you care about tail recursion, you can write a slightly less straightforward function.)

Comment: thank you for your answer, yes that what i did but i want to know how init works because i didn't use it before especially when we want to recuperate at each time a different value

Comment: Well, `List.init` is applicable pretty much only in cases where the elements of the list can be calculated based on their position in the list (and on nothing else). Since your case isn't like this, there's no advantage (IMHO) in figuring out how to use `List.init` for it. Instead maybe try using `List.init` to transform an array into a list (say).

Comment: @maya if the values you want to recuperate aren't the index integers in the range `0..n-1` where `n` is the first argument of `List.init`, then like Jeffrey said it's pretty self-defeating.

Answer (score 0):

using a recursive function will increase the complexity so i think that initializing directly the list (or array) at the corresponding length will be better but i don't really know how to get a different value at each _i like Jeffrey Scofield said i am not really familiar with ocaml especially sequences so i have some difficulties doing that:(

Comment: Try taking the `init_aux` function described below and replacing `f` with your sequence `s`. The head of `s` gives `r` and its tail should be passed to the recursive call.

Comment: Using recursion does not increase the complexity. `List.init` is implemented as a recursive function. Recursion is the normal way to solve problems in OCaml. (But you do need to learn to recognize and use tail recursion, that I will admit.)

Comment: @maya soft reminder: please post this as a comment instead of an answer or it may be flagged for removal later.